# How to use asset names involving Unicode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicode, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have a number of audio file names that I need to support which are written in Chinese romanization, for example `wǒ shì xuésheng.mp3`. There seems to be a problem translating these into asset paths or handling the resulting paths, as

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/wǒ shì xuésheng.mp3
http://localhost:3000/assets/w%C7%92+sh%C3%AC+xu%C3%A9sheng.mp3
http://localhost:3000/assets/w%C7%92%20sh%C3%AC%20xu%C3%A9sheng.mp3
```

Don't result in anything. I tried asset_path and Rack encode, but there seems to be no way to access these files that are in my directory structure. In order to eliminate potential error sources, I also tried with a file named `ma ma.mp3` in the same directory and that one loads fine, so the problem seems to be with the Unicode characters in the file names.

Funnily enough, File.exists works:

```
File.exists?(File.join(Rails.root, "/app/assets/audios/", "wǒ shì xuésheng.mp3"))
```

Also, European diacritics work:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/bù.mp3
```

Just Unicode ones break the system.

I'm using Rails 3.2.11 and Ruby 1.9.3. (EDIT: this issue persists even in Rails 4.0.2)

EDIT: I suspect it's a problem with the asset pipeline because I also cannot do a rake assets:precompile while I have Unicode characters in a filename, it fails with "undefined method directory? for nil:NilClass".

EDIT: this is the trace for rake assets:precompile:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=produ
ction RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
undefined method `directory?' for nil:NilClass
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:189:in `block in each_en
try'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:185:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:185:in `each_entry'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_fi
le'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_pat
h'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `comp
ile'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_pr
ecompile'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 le
vels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call
_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 le
vels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call
_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) i
n top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level
'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception
_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe C...]
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:55:in `block in create_shel
l_runner'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in `ruby'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_t
ask'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_r
eboot_rake_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 le
vels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call
_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) i
n top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level
'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception
_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: what's the browser doing when you go to the first url? can you share the complete stacktrace while doing assets:precompile?

Comment: I just edited the post to add the trace. When I go to one of the urls, the browser invariably says "No route matches [GET] "/assets/w%C7%92%20sh%C3%AC%20xu%C3%A9sheng.mp3""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with different handling of Unicode filenames on Windows, Mac and Linux. I tried running the same code on a friend's Linux computer and the same code runs perfectly there.

Since File.exists? works but the asset-related code doesn't, I believe that the asset-related code has not been written from a platform-independent point of view, while the File utilities have. I'm submitting a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

There've been a large number of bug fixes in the Rails 3.2.x patch releases that may have addressed this issue.  Other posts here have implied that upgrading to 3.2.14 fixes this UTF-8 URL encoding issue.

I recommend upgrading to `Rails 3.2.15` (current patch release) to see if this issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the idea; I have upgraded but the problem persists.